# How to solve the puzzle below?

Tags: mathematics, grid-deduction

Someone send me a puzzle in Discord and the creator said you can ask other people to help me solve. Here is one of the problems I can't solve.
[image: 1]

Could anyone help me? It is hard!

Comment: rot13(Guvf vf onfvpnyyl n qhcyvpngr bs chmmyvat.fgnpxrkpunatr.pbz/d/54560/39583. Urer gur cbfvgvbaf ner whfg qrgrezvarq ol gur cerivbhf ahzore vafgrnq bs gur sbyybjvat bar.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer:

> \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline1&5&4&3&6&8&9&2&7\\\hline5&7&6&3&4&8&1&9&2\\\hline9&5&4&8&7&3&6&1&2\\\hline2&9&6&8&4&1&3&7&5\\\hline3&9&7&1&2&8&5&4&6\\\hline2&8&9&6&4&3&1&5&7\\\hline5&8&1&3&7&4&2&9&6\\\hline3&9&7&2&8&5&4&1&6\\\hline6&8&9&1&4&3&2&5&7\\\hline\end{array}

Thought process:

> I saw the last 2 digits of the 3rd line, which was a $1$ followed by a $2$.
> I then spotted that the 1st digit of the 4th line was a $2$.
> In sight of this, I made a wild guess: The numbers are in the position determined by the number in front of them in the previous row.
> And apparently I got it correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing that could be noted is that the grid contains

> a lot of powers of 3: 1, 3 and 9 evenly spaced in the top row; 27 spelled as 72 in the right column, 81 in the top right, 243 (but it's more scattered across the grid).

Then

> only a 2, 6, and 8 are not accounted for. Perhaps this is a pattern of powers of 2, and the 4 and 16 somehow coincide with the powers of 3?